# Update tabbarcontroller badge from a static struct

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure if this is possible or if I'm going about this the wrong way but...

I have an ecommerce app. You can add products to your cart. I'd like to display a badge over cart with the item quantity in the cart.

However, my Cart is in a static struct which needs to update the tabbarController.

How can I get these two to communicate between each other?

Cart

```
import Foundation
struct Cart {
    static var items: [CartItem] = []

    static func updateItem(id:Int,increment:Int){
        var itemAdded = false

        for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
            if item.fabric.id == id {
                item.quantity = item.quantity+increment
                if item.quantity <= 0 {
                    items.remove(at: index)
                }
                itemAdded = true
            }
        }


        if !itemAdded {
            // fabric not in cart
            // add it
            for item in API.fabrics{
                if item.id == id{
                    items.append(CartItem(fabric: item, quantity: 1))
                    return
                }
            }
        }


          // AREA IN QUESTION
//        let MainTabBarController = AppDelegate
//        if let tabItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items{
//            
//        }
    }



}

class CartItem{
    let fabric: Fabric
    var quantity: Int

    init(fabric: Fabric,
         quantity: Int){
        self.fabric = fabric
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}
```

app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let MainTabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController")


    window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Where is the tab bar controller in terms of the overall  view controller hierarchy? Also, where does the Cart object live?

Comment: @matt tabbarcontroller is the rootviewcontroller

Comment: @matt the Cart object is just a static struct that is accessible from anywhere in the app

Comment: “tabbarcontroller is the rootviewcontroller” Then the problem is solved.

Comment: I Think your approach needs a bit of change. The class should be struct and the struct should be class. You can always update the struct using mutating func thus you can achieve your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tabbarcontroller is the rootviewcontroller

```
if let tabbarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as?  MainTabBarController{
    tabbarControllertabBar.items[indexpOfTabbarItem]!.badgeValue = value
}
```

if rootviewcontroller is navigationcontroller of tabbarcontroller:

```
if let tabbarNavigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController, let tabbarController = tabbarNavigationController.viewControllers.first as? MainTabBarController  {
    tabbarControllertabBar.items[indexpOfTabbarItem]!.badgeValue = value
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a `var` instead of a `let`? `UITabBarController` is a class, so `let` should "just work" as it is an object and not a struct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSNotificationcenter.post(_ notification: Notification)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1410472-post), so everytime you add an item to your cart you post a notification, and the your `TabController` can subscribe to this notification and handle it. Something like:

```
import NotificationCenter
import UIKit

struct Cart {

    func add(item: Int) {
        // Your code to handle stuff...
        let numberOfItems = item
        let notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "addItem"), object: nil, userInfo: ["numberOfItems":numberOfItems])
        NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
    }

}

class YourTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAddItem), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "addItem"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleAddItem(notification: Notification) {
        // increment badge value
        tabBar.items?.first?.badgeValue = "\(notification.userInfo!["numberOfItems"]!)"
    }

}
```

Of course, you can do the same thing to remove items and every other stuff you need.

Comment: I too accept your point to achieve the goal of what the user has asked for. But architecture wise there are more better ways to achieve the same rather than posting the notification from struct!

Comment: Sure there are @KarthickRamesh, thanks for point it out! Since I don't have full knowledge of op's application, to know what could be a better or worse architecture, I just wanted to keep it as close as possible to op's implementation.